Can't get past "Exception binding parameter" when trying to use ServiceBusTrigger
I'm writing my first ServiceBusTriggered Azure function, but am failing to get it to execute successfully.
Connection to the queue is working and the function is attempting to execute when I inject a message (which I'm doing via the Service Bus Explorer in Azure portal). The message is also moved to the dead letter queue after failing for the configured number of retries, as expected.
Here's the code:
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace PlayerProcessing.PendingPlayerCustomId;

public class QueueWorker
{
    private readonly ILogger _log;

    public QueueWorker(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _log = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<QueueWorker>>();
    }
    
    [FunctionName("ServiceBusQueueTriggerCSharp")]                    
    public void Run(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("pending-player-custom-id", Connection = "AzureServiceBus")] 
        string myQueueItem
    )
    {
        _log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
    }
}

(I initially tried using a JSON object and the application/json content type, but I haven't even been able to get it working with a string and text/plain content type.)
The error I get:

System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: ServiceBusQueueTriggerCSharp. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'myQueueItem'.

Thanks!

    [ServiceBusTrigger("queue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection", IsBatched = true)] ServiceBusReceivedMessage[] messages)

Have you tried somethink like this ?

@Bilal Akil Have you added the "AzureServiceBus": "ServiceBusQueueConnectionString" in the local.settings.json.

@DasariKamali Yes, it is connecting successfully and receiving the messages - it's just failing to execute them with the mentioned binding exception, and then sending them to the dead letter queue.

I created a sample ServiceBusQueueTrigger function and successfully got the message from Azure Service Bus Queue.

The connection may not be retrieved correctly, or it could have expired due to improper configuration in the local.settings.json file

Make sure you have added the Azure Service Bus Queue connection string in the local.settings.json file as below.


local.settings.json :
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<StoragecConneString>",
    "FUNCTIONS_INPROC_NET8_ENABLED": "1",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "AzureServiceBus": "<ServiceBusQueueConnecString>"
  }
}

Code :
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
 
namespace FunctionApp2.PendingPlayerCustomId
{
    public class QueueWorker
    {
        [FunctionName("ServiceBusQueueTriggerCSharp")]
        public void Run(
            [ServiceBusTrigger("pending-player-custom-id", Connection = "AzureServiceBus")]
            string myQueueItem,
            ILogger log 
        )
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
        }
    }
}

Azure Service Bus Queue :
I sent a message to the Azure Service Bus Queue as shown below.

Output :
The Service Bus Queue trigger function ran successfully as shown below.


Are you able to share your .csproj file? I’d like to try matching your plugin versions.

Actually this was enough to help me over the line, thank you! I was able to create a new project just like yours, and that worked fine. Then I compared package differences and got the existing project to more closely match the new project, and suddenly it started working

@Bilal Akil I'm glad to know the issue was resolved.
